# Website broken with message "Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"?"

Tags: php, wordpress

Working on WordPress with Jupiter Theme. I cannot determine when this error occurred but here's what it is:

Go to website www.coloradopcbassembly.com. Two things are different than when I left it 2 weeks ago:

1. The spacing and formatting is different - there are huge page breaks
2. I cannot click on menu items
3. There are huge errors on the top of the page, as follows:

> Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you
>   mean to use "continue 2"? in
>   /home3/colorcl3/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/operations.class.php
>   on line 2854
>
> Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you
>   mean to use "continue 2"? in
>   /home3/colorcl3/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/operations.class.php
>   on line 2858
>
> Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you
>   mean to use "continue 2"? in
>   /home3/colorcl3/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/output.class.php
>   on line 3708
>
> Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you
>   mean to use "continue 2"? in
>   /home3/colorcl3/public_html/wp-content/themes/jupiter/framework/includes/minify/src/Minifier.php
>   on line 227

I am not a developer. I am a business owner, learning WordPress as I go. As of 2 weeks ago, the site was fine, however, here are the changes:

10/30/19 - I added a few pages and buttons, really nothing major (that I can think of)
10/30/19 - I installed a plugin called Duplicate Post by By Enrico Battocchi (I have deactivated that to see if it fixes the issue; it does not)
11/12/19 - WordPress updated to version 5.3

Here's the problem: I don't know if this break in the website occurred yesterday when WordPress updated to 5.3 or if this happened 2 weeks ago on 10/30/19 when I made updates. I don't know where to go from here, but this is the train I'm on:

1. Roll back WordPress to whatever it was before (I don't know how to do this)
2. Disable Revolution Slider (the revslider error on 3 of the 4 messages)
3. Roll back changes somehow? Just somehow make the page what it was 2 weeks ago?

Last note: Of the 3 ideas above, I have disabled Slider Revolution, and it does remove 3 of the 4 errors. It does not fix the formatting or the 4th error, though. I re-enabled Slider Revolution solely for the purpose of this post, so you guys could see the error in all its glory - and so anyone kind enough to help me wouldn't think this error is just with the Jupiter directory.

2 updates: in my research, I'm finding many people with this error associating it with PHP7.3.

Also, I went to my theme homepage to submit a ticket and they show this error: "Please do not upgrade your WordPress to 5.3 Until Jupiter X 1.13 is out
There is a compatibility issue with Jupiter X, Raven and WP 5.3 which is currently fixed and is waiting to be released. It is highly recommended to not to update WordPress to 5.3 until Jupiter X 1.13 is out. "

Well of course it updated last night automatically - but I think this must be it, right?

Next update: I downgraded from Wordpress 5.3 back to version 5.2.4 (confirmed no bug). It did not work.

SOLVED!!!!! Here is the answer for anyone who comes across this thread in the future. I have copied and pasted the recommendation from Artbees support (theme dev):

Usually, the warning "Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"?" appears when PHP version 7.3 is used. Downgrading to PHP 7.1 or 7.2 will fix it.

Otherwise, add this code in the wp-config.php file before the line "/* That's all, stop editing! Happy publishing. */":

`ini_set('display_errors','Off');`
`define('WP_DEBUG', false);`
`define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);`

Comment: Hi! Have you updated your servers/hosting PHP Version, too?

Comment: No, I have not updated my servers/hosting PHP version (unless that's something that would have happened automatically with the Wordpress 5.3 update). I also tried to roll back from WP 5.3 to WP 5.2.4 (last known good version) since my post and the issue is still here.

Comment: If you are seeing these Warnings on your site, that means you have debug mode turned on.  This is _not_ recommended for production sites.  I'd say turn off debug mode, disable the slider, wait for the Jupiter update, and call it a day. Then I'd nuke the WP install and use something else, but that's just a personal feeling :)

Comment: Hi Patrick, I first went to my wp-config.php to check if debug was turned on - it's not. I found line 82 shows "define('WP_DEBUG', false);" which means I'm not on debug mode - is that right?

Comment: Issue solved - Here is the answer for anyone who comes across this thread in the future. I have copied and pasted the recommendation from Artbees support (theme dev):

Usually, the warning "Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"?" appears when PHP version 7.3 is used. Downgrading to PHP 7.1 or 7.2 will fix it.

Otherwise, add this code in the wp-config.php file before the line "/* That's all, stop editing! Happy publishing. */":

ini_set('display_errors','Off'); define('WP_DEBUG', false); define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);

Comment: @ErinStecher You should submit this as an answer and mark it as resolved instead of burying it in the comments and adding it to your question. Also, I have posted a simple solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61063886/warning-continue-targeting-switch-is-equivalent-to-break/66724431#66724431

Answer (score 1):

HOW I SOLVED !!!

For me downgrading `php` version wasn't possible.
Didn't work disabling `php` errors and warnings

```
ini_set('display_errors','Off'); define('WP_DEBUG', false); define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
```

So what I did is

```
1.  /home3/colorcl3/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/operations.class.php 2253
       commented continue; and ended if with ;
    if(!isset($layer['video_data']->id) || empty($layer['video_data']->id));// continue;

 2. /home3/colorcl3/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/operations.class.php 2257
       commented continue; and ended if with ;
    if(!isset($layer['video_data']->id) || empty($layer['video_data']->id));// continue;

 3. /home3/colorcl3/public_html/wp-content/plugins/revslider/includes/output.class.php on line 3163
   commented continue; 
    case 'none':
        //continue;
    break;
```

4. I got an array issue in base-admin.class.php file

```
    change private static $arrMetaBoxes = '';  to private static $arrMetaBoxes = array();
```

I know this is not the proper solution but didnt get any other solution.